# Parsing and greping html in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have html page in my product site, I want to get parse the document and get product versions from the html page.

html page would look like this:

```
<html>
.......
.......
<body>
.......
.......
<div id='version_info'>
    <div class="product-version">
        <div class="product-title">Name of the product 1:</div><div class="product-value">ver_123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-version">
        <div class="product-title">Name of the product 2:</div><div class="product-value">ver_456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-version">
        <div class="product-title">Name of the product 3:</div><div class="product-value">ver_845</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-version">
        <div class="product-title">Name of the product 4:</div><div class="product-value">ver_146</div>
    </div>  
</div>
.......
.......
</body>
.......
.......
</html>
```

how can I grep the document and form strings something like this?
productname1=ver_123,productname2=ver_456,productname3=ver_845,etc

Comment: Do you need answer for this particular format of HTML? Or it can be different?

Comment: It would be good if I get answer for this HTML. But if you have similar example, that would also be of great help.

Comment: grepping xml/html, now you have two problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked on this particular HTML file and in result i am getting a dictionary of required variables under variable `result`

**Note:**

> **1.** Please change path of html file in playbook.
>
> **2.** This particular playbook work for this HTML example. For further requirements and improvements provide HTML.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: "Getting varibles from HTML"
  vars:
   result: {}
  tasks:
  - name: "Getting content of the file"
    command: cat /path/to/html/file
    register: search
  - name: "Creating dictionary while Looping over file"
    ignore_errors: true
    vars:
     key: "{{item | replace('<div class=\"product-title\">','') | replace('</div>','') | regex_replace('<div.*','') | regex_replace('^\\s*','')}}"
     value: "{{item | replace('<div class=\"product-title\">','') | replace('</div>','') | regex_replace('^[\\w\\s\\:]*','') | replace('<div class=\"product-value\">','') | regex_replace('\\s*$','')}}" 
    set_fact:
     result: "{{ result | combine( { key: value } ) }}"
    when: "'product-title' in item"
    with_items: "{{search.stdout_lines}}"

  - name: "Getting register"
    debug:
     msg: "{{result}}"  
...
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "Name of the product 1:": "ver_123", 
        "Name of the product 2:": "ver_456", 
        "Name of the product 3:": "ver_845", 
        "Name of the product 4:": "ver_146"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check your code today and let you know :)

Comment: @SRNathan I see it's been almost 7 months since this post, but it looks like Sahil solved your problem; you should accept it. If you solved it on your own and his answer helped, consider accepting it and provide your solution as an edit in your OP.